# How do I use verticalAlign on a non-floating title/subtitle?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fggr567e/

The problem I have is that I want to have a subtitle (or something that achieves a similar effect) on the bottom left of the chart, but not have it behave as floating, i.e., have the chart automatically adjust the spacing based on the subtitle height, the same way the title does when the  `floating` property is false. The legend seems to already work this way so I am not sure how to achieve the same with the subtitle.

Edit: I'd ideally like to keep the title where it is.

Comment: I've moved this question to the highcharts forum directly and the response I got was a simple "no". (http://forum.highcharts.com/post120303.html#p120303)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've moved my question over to the highcharts support forum and this is the response I have received:

> There is no option to do that.
>
> One way could be to place the subtitle outside the chart, under chart's container.
>
> Other solution might be to dynamically change bottom margin after each chart.redraw event and readjust position of a custom text element created via renderer to be used instead of Highcharts' subtitle. Recalculating space need for the text will also resolve the problem with subtitle not returning to a bigger size after change of width (being increased) of chart's container.

In short there's no way to do this natively in highcharts.

In the end I did what was suggested in the first line, placed the subtitle outside the chart as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/fggr567e/1/

**JS:-**

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({                
                "chart": {
                    "renderTo": "chart-2",
                    "type": "column",
                     //This works but I need to calculate this based on the subtitle height which is not ideal 
                     //spacingBottom: 40 
                },           
                title:{
                     verticalAlign: "bottom",
                    align: "left",
                    floating: false,                   
                    "text": ""
                },
                "subtitle": {
                    verticalAlign: "bottom",
                    align: "left",
                    floating: false,                   
                    "text": "Subtitle"
                },
                "series": [ { data: [112800, 134409] } ]
            });
});
```

Comment: I have to admit, this works, though it's not ideal since you can't really use a top aligned title and a bottom aligned subtitle in this case.

Comment: @apokryfos Looks like this is the only way to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this doesn't work for me. When the subtitle is too long and is forced to wrap the second line disappears. I guess JavaScript calculations it is.

Comment: @apokryfos Please let me know the subTitle text for which it's breaking.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fggr567e/3/ it's got manual line breaks, but you get the idea

Comment: @apokryfos Does this answer your query?

Comment: Unfortunately no. That y: -30 you've specified is hard-coded and will not be applicable if the subtitle is of a different length. The whole point of my question is that I want highcharts to automatically adjust the chart in order to properly fit the title, chart, legend and subtitle without overlaps and without anything being clipped. Unfortunately Highcharts support says this can't be done.